# conflicting types when trying to pass an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

i tried to write a program in C:

Here is a piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i, left, right, largest = 0, n = 9;
int a[] = {23, 12, 22, 1, 4, 5, 16, 8, 9, 10};
int main()
{
 sort(a);
 //code to print sorted numbers here
 return 0;

}

void sort(int a[])
{
 buildheap(a);
 for(i = n; i < 0; i--)
 {
  exchange(i, 0);
  n = n - 1;
  maxheap(a, 0);
 }
}
```

It shows warnings like this:

```
heapsort.c:16: warning: conflicting types for âsortâ
```

Is this because i'm nto including `conio.h` ?

When i tried to include conio.h, the gcc compiler throws error that conio.h is not found.

Any link or explanation in detail about the above warning and its relevance/irrelevance to conio.h will be helpful

## Update

Im sorry for missing basics here.

Thank you so much. My program is running fine now

Comment: For one thing, your for loop will never execute, since n will be greater than 0 initially

Comment: if possible do not use globals

Comment: thank you so much. I have changed the condition to i > 0. I will try not to use global variables, it is throwing a segmentation fault anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because there is no declaration of `sort()` prior to its use. If a function is not declared (or defined) before it is used an implicit declaration is generated (the compiler should have emitted *implicit declaration* warnings) with signature `int sort()`. Either add a declaration or move the definition to before `main()`.

Possibly same problem with `buildheap()`, `exchange()` and `maxheap()`: I don't recognise any of these functions.